# Check class of generic object variable

Tags: java

I am writing a function that tests whether variable of type Object is of a given type. For example, if I put in `"This is a string"` and `String.class` as the params, it should return true.

I have tried the following code:

```
public static boolean Debug(Object variable, Class<?> testClass) {
    if (variable instanceof testClass) {
            return true;
    }
    return false
}
```

However, I got the error: "testClass cannot be resolved to a type".

I am not quite sure why this is.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you can't have variable as the right argument of the `instanceof` operator, it has to be a concrete class/interface

Comment: Well, "abc" is not instance of a `Class`, even if Class *describes* String class. You may want to use `testClass.isInstance(variable)`. But to be honest usually this represents [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), can you explain *why* do you want to create such code?

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions. The method should be called `debug` (camelCase, not PascalCase).

Comment: And not sure about the many upvotes here ... it is really not like the OP did a lot of prior research it seems ...

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica Correct!

Comment: Agreed. But imo the question is pretty clear and well posted. Enough to be worth no down-vote at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is correct: `testClass` is *not* a type, it's an *object*, of type `Class<String>`. The `instanceof` operator can only be used with types that are given at compile time. Instead, you can do your check with the [`Class#isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) method of your `Class` object:

```
public static boolean Debug(Object variable, Class<?> testClass) {
    if (testClass.isInstance(variable)) {
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

A better way to write that would be:

```
public static boolean Debug(Object variable, Class<?> testClass) {
    return testClass.isInstance(variable);
}
```

At this point, it's so small that I would start to wonder whether this method is worth having at all.

Comment: ... at which point the method is more or less obsolete since it is just an alias to a more clear method call `testClass.isInstance(variable)` vs `Debug(variable, testClass)`.

Comment: Although correct, I question the value of such a method. Instead of calling `Debug(someVariable, String.class)`, why not simply call `String.class.isInstance(someVariable)` beforehand?

Comment: @Zabuza Of course, but that is left as an exercise to the reader ;)